# Form Library and Attachment

Tags: infopath, attachments

Is it possible to add an attachment to a form library?

I tried publishing a form that has an attachment control but getting "The selected field cannot be promoted because its data type is not supported: base64binary"

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Yes. The selected field cannot be promoted because its data type is not supported: base64binary

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible - you will have to store (add/remove) the attachements in a different document library. You'll have to do the adding/removing yourself - either with custom code (in your InfoPath Form or better in a custom WebService) or OOTB WebServices.

[Here](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments/) is a good article about the Top 10 Questions about InfoPath File Attachements. See Point Nr. 5 for uploading to different document libraries.

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepoint2010customization/thread/c74939ee-44d4-41ac-ac89-5a4b053fe110

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/10912/38828.aspx

It appears Base64Binary is not allowed as a promoted property. You need to write custom code to upload the file to the Document Library instead of as an attachment control.