# Document to Appear in the Forms Library and InfoPath Form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, custom-form, form

Created a Form library in SharePoint and using a InfoPath form to collect data.  In the form is a Attachment control to add documents.  Adding documents to the InfoPath form attached to my Form Library the document is only accessed in the InfoPath form.  Is there a way for the document to be available in the InfoPath form and also in the  Forms library as a metadata column similar to using document library in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This by design, you cannot promote an attachment field in InfoPath - it's something that's not supported when publishing InfoPath to SharePoint.

Here is a similar post:
[Form Library and Attachment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42165/form-library-and-attachment)